# Why should I use const and & while declaring class in function?

Tags: c++, function, class, memory, constants

I don't get the point at all. I just know that; if I don't write like this

```
void samplefunctionname(const randomclass &classmember) {
  //code goes here...
}
```

the function will copy every information in classmember to itself. So it's not good for memory. Maybe I just want to write classmember's variables that are chosen by me, but if I do not write const and & it will just write all of the information.

But what actually these guys are doing ? Why class should be const etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Why should I use const and & while declaring class in function?

In order to avoid copying the *whole* class. When you use `const&`, you pass the object by reference, which doesn't copy any data at all.

Comment: Which doesn't copy *any data at all*.